# Declaration merging doesn't work for Interfaces

Tags: typescript, stripe-payments

I'm trying to add a custom field to `Stripe.Subscription` using https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html but it doesn't work.

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';

export {};

// Looks like this mwrhod also doesn't work.
// declare global {
//     interface Subscription {
//         role: string;
//     }
// }

// This might also be the wrong way to declare it as it's not using the imported Stripe namespace as all.
declare global {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-namespace
    namespace Stripe {
        interface Subscription {
            role: string;
        }
    }
}

Stripe.Subscription.prototype.role: string = this['role']; // <= Error: TS2339: Property 'Subscription' does not exist on type 'typeof import("stripe")'.
```

Then if I try to access `role`:

```
const subscription: Stripe.Subscription = getSubscription();
subscription.role; // <= TS2339: Property 'role' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.
```

Here's the `Subscription` interface declaration https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/547d9d34d07f3dbcee131fb0a00368b09ed37741/types/Subscriptions.d.ts#L10

Comment: You say that declaration "doesn't work for interfaces", but it's working perfectly here.  When you write `Stripe.Subscription`, you are apparently expecting there to be a class constructor *value* named `Subscription` exported by stripe and there isn't one.  Interfaces are types, and class constructors are values, and just because you have a named interface it does not imply that there is also a named value that constructs instances of that interface.  Such things *do* happen with `class` declarations, but I don't see a `class` here anywhere in your code.

Comment: ...Anyway, you might want to [edit] the question so that the title more accurately describes your problem, which is apparently specific to stripe, so that you have a better chance to get the right eyes on the question. Right now it's kind of XY-problem-ish; your underlying issue is in adding a custom property to subscriptions in stripe (if I've phrased that right, I have no idea what stripe even is, really) and you thought declaration merging would let you do that; instead of asking about a failed attempt, just ask about your underlying issue.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make sure to follow the same declaration pattern as the original library:

```
declare module 'stripe' {
    namespace Stripe {
        interface Subscription {
            /** Attached JSDoc */
            role: string;
        }
    }
}

declare const subscription: Stripe.Subscription;
subscription.role; // Okay
//           ^? string
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAZRlYYCmcBmUIjgIgGdlU18BuAKEoBM0BjAGwEMoMQIaBXRjAcmIp0fOAG9KcSXAB2zEGkJhm9DEiEZxUrXGDSYaKJmWquAI0L0hMYBGliJ2xwHoAVC7gBBGDGUALNDRwAFIIACIQ9HAuTg6OWji8AFxwgroA5lRxcAC+sTmUubQMLGxw9LbEKWYWVjbSyWqkAHQI1Zao1rZUhG21tk0JaORwTk5wAPIA1swAnpSjWVIAegD8lEA)

Comment: What about the `role` value, how do I define it? `Stripe.Subscription.prototype` still gives me the same error: TS2339: Property 'Subscription' does not exist on type 'typeof Stripe'.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do there? Do you want to define a default value? If so, this sounds like a different question, as it depends on how Stripe creates the Subscription.

Comment: The `Subscription` interface is mapping the json response from Stripe API. The json object has an additional key `role` which is not in the `Subscription` interface. I want to safely extend `Subscription` interface to define this additional field.

Comment: Here is what I understand from your description: Stripe API response is a `Subscription`, except that in runtime, you see an extra `role` key that is not declared in the interface, but which you want to use (read and/or write to). And TS warns you that the type misses it. In that case, the above answer covers your use case already. If you want to write into that key, you can just do so: https://tsplay.dev/mZQ2EN I still do not understand what you are trying to achieve with `Stripe.Subscription.prototype` sorry.

Comment: What is this `role` field and if it's part of the Stripe API's JSON response why doesn't Stripe's official Typescript definitions contain it already?

Comment: I included a simplified use case, but the `role` property is nested. Anyway the @ghybs solutions works perfectly. The whole confusion was around other solutions I found on Stackoverflow which were also setting the field on the prototype. Now I understand it only applies for classes.